# how close ant design dropdown manually?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, antd

I have a DropDown like this and I want close it automatically after submitting form.
How can i do this?

```
<Dropdown
 overlay={<form onSubmit={()=>{/* close dropdown */}}></form>}
 trigger={["click"]}
>
  open
</Dropdown>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage this need with `visible` property of [Dropdown](https://ant.design/components/dropdown/) component. Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/p4jcl) for more infos.